# What is the feminine noun for 'benedict'?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms, analogy

I came across the word 'benedict' recently:

> Benedict: A name for a newly married man, esp if formerly a confirmed bachelor

Is there an equivalent feminine noun for a newly married woman? 'Bride' won't do, as we need to refer to woman after the marriage.

Comment: I'd say there isn't one.  *Newlywed* is a nice word, though not gender-specific.

Comment: Is that what that menas? I thought it just meant 'blessed', literally 'spoken well of'. Where did you get that meaning?

Comment: I suggest coining a new term — benedicta.

Comment: @Mitch, [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benedict) has it as _: a newly married man who has long been a bachelor_ and goes on to offer the origin as 'alteration of Benedick, character in Shakespeare's Much Ado About Nothing
(First Known Use: 1821)'.

Comment: The feminine version of the name Benedict is Beneditta, but I don't think it means a newly married woman.

Comment: I think I can confidantly say that while you might find this word in a dictionary, if you try to use it in speech or writing, absolutely no one will know what you're talking about.

Comment: In the US if you call someone a benedict, they may take it as a reference to Benedict Arnold, and not to Benedick in Shakespeare.

Comment: If you want to coin a new word and given that benedict originated with Shakespeare's Benedick, then I think the only fitting word would be *Beatrict*

Comment: Within Greek Orthodox society in the USA, a bride is a bride (nymphia) until she has the couple's first child. There may be other groups that use "bride" to mean newlywed.

Comment: @GEdgar just encountered Benedict in the wild for the first time last night, and made exactly this mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the etymology of this sense of the word 'benedict', I would not expect to find any true feminine forms (other than neologisms).

From the OED:

> **1.B.1** A newly married man; *esp.* an apparently confirmed bachelor who marries. [From the character of that name in Shakes. *Much Ado
>   about Nothing*.]
>
> [**1599** Shakes. *Much Ado* v. iv. 100 How dost thou Benedicke the
>   married man?]    **1821** Scott in *Lockhart* (1839) VI. 313 Wish the
>   veteran joy of his entrance into the band of Benedicts.    **1843**
>   *Life in West* (L.) He is no longer a benedick, but a quiet married man.

Your initial choice is actually probably your best bet.  'Bride' can refer to a recently married woman and this sense has been in use since at least 1000 CE.  From the OED for 'bride':

> **1.a** A woman at her marriage; a woman just about to be married or very recently married.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no one single word for this idea, as there is for a man. However, while looking up the [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/bride), an option came up, that is: "newly married woman".

That seems to be the clearest to me. I know it's not as catchy, and it's not a single word, but its meaning is quite clear.